# How to retain use selected option in radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I have a text form that uses a radio button of two options. For example, the 'exact match' is checked by default. However, whenever the 'submit'  is clicked, the option reverts back to the default section, which is undesired. I want to retain the radio option currently selected by users, not the default one.

```
<form class="search" action="{{ url_for('nlp.wbkg') }}" method="post">

        <input name="query" type="text" id="query" value="{{query}}" autocomplete="on" required>
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        <div>
       
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="exact" value="exact" checked="checked"> Exact match </input>
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="fuzzy" value="fuzzy"> Fuzzy Match </input>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How to achieve that effect?

EDIT: add my server-side code in flask:

```
@bp.route('/wbkg', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def wbkg():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['query']
        search_type = request.form['options']
       
        results, terms = search(query, search_type)
           
        return render_template('nlp/wbkg.html', items=results, terms=terms, query=query)

        flash(error)

    return render_template('nlp/wbkg.html')
```

How to handle it in server side?

Comment: Do it server side when you process the form

Comment: @charlietfl I added my server-side code. How can I do it in server side?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wrapping your element in a form tag you should be sure to have your submit handler run event.preventDefault() to prevent the resetting of the form after the submit is fired.  You may be witnessing the reset of the form after the API call was sent.  You can confirm this by looking at your REQ body to see if the data sent is correct.

Comment: Unless OP implements ajax submit there will be no api call if you preventDefault. No indication of that happening here

Comment: How can I use ajax to achieve in front end, if possible? I am new to this.